# How to Pass Parameter from HTML to CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the color from the database for each photo like below:

[image]

I'd like to pass this color to css. For what I want to achieve is, to have this color Transparent over the image with opacity 0.7. When I mouse hover it, it will change the opacity to 1. That's the reason why I want to pass it to CSS.

How can I achieve this? I really don't want to use Javascript or jQuery for this. I'd like to use pure CSS only.

I'm thinking of using inline element, How's that sound?

Thanks.

Comment: CSS is for styling only, you cannot pass parameters to or from it. You're going to have to use JS (or whatever language you're using server side)

Comment: I end up using inline element <div class="client-overlay" style="background-color: <?php echo $client_bg_color; ?>"> </div>. Then apply opacity to class client-overlay.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use javascript.

e.g.

`<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.color = 'red'">`

(taken from http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

Comment: You could also use the :hover property of css e.g. .MyClass:hover { css } however the values of a css stylesheet cannot be dynamically changed without javascript.